# QGIS use only certain plugins for each project

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgs

I would like to make use of certain plugins for each project.

Instead having to disable installed plugins for a particular project, I would like to select the one(s) that I want to use on the project in hand.

How can I do this?

Do I have to create a different profile for each project?